# Python instance methods vs static methods

Tags: python, python-2.7, generics

I try to learn Python 2.7. When i run this code:

```
class MyClass:
    def PrintList1(*args):
        for Count, Item in enumerate(args):
            print("{0}. {1}".format(Count, Item))

    def PrintList2(**kwargs):
        for Name, Value in kwargs.items():
            print("{0} likes {1}".format(Name, Value))

MyClass.PrintList1("Red", "Blue", "Green")
MyClass.PrintList2(George="Red", Sue="Blue",Zarah="Green")
```

i get a `TypeError`:

```
MyClass.PrintList1("Red", "Blue", "Green")
TypeError: unbound method PrintList1() must be called with MyClass instance    as first argument (got str instance instead)
>>>
```

Why?

Comment: Why are you trying to call an instance method on the class, and where's your `self` parameter? Frankly, there seems to be no point these methods being in a class at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyClass is, a class.

PrintList1 is a method.

Methods needs to be called on instanciated objects of the class.

Like this:

```
myObject = MyClass()
myObject.PrintList1("Red", "Blue", "Green")
myObject.PrintList2(George="Red", Sue="Blue", Zarah="Green")
```

For this to work properly, you also need to make your methods take the `self` argument, like this:

```
class MyClass:
    def PrintList1(self, *args):
        for Count, Item in enumerate(args):
            print("{0}. {1}".format(Count, Item))

    def PrintList2(self, **kwargs):
        for Name, Value in kwargs.items():
            print("{0} likes {1}".format(Name, Value))
```

If you want to call your code as static functions, you need to add the staticmethod decorator to your class, like this:

```
class MyClass:
    @staticmethod
    def PrintList1(*args):
        for Count, Item in enumerate(args):
            print("{0}. {1}".format(Count, Item))

    @staticmethod
    def PrintList2(**kwargs):
        for Name, Value in kwargs.items():
            print("{0} likes {1}".format(Name, Value))

MyClass.PrintList1("Red", "Blue", "Green")
MyClass.PrintList2(George="Red", Sue="Blue",Zarah="Green")
```